# apply function for indexing in r

Tags: r, indexing, apply, subset

I have a vector `V<-1:10`,

I want to select three elements of V for many times.
E.g
for the first time,   I will select the firs three elements `a[1:3]`,
for the second time,  I would like to select`a[2:4]`,
for the third time, `a[7:9]`
the output will be 
 
`[1,]  2  3  8

[2,]  3  4  9

[3,]  4  5  10`

Any tricks to make is faster,  if I repeat this sub-setting process many times, it is really slow.  or how to use apply function family to solve these problem. My current solution is 
 
`Index <- function(id, DM)  DM[id]
 Metrix <- apply(b,2,Index, a)`
where b is as follows: 
 
`[1,]  1  2  7

[2,]  2  3  8

[3,]  3  4  9`

Can someone use the build-in function instead of my own Index function.

Comment: Could you show the expected output based on `a`

Comment: like a1 a2 <br> [1,] 1 2 <br> [2,] 2 3<br> [3,] 3 4<br>

Comment: Be specific about what you want to implement on the subvectors, otherwise this is an open-ended question.

Comment: I have changed my questions, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use `rollapply` from the `zoo` package.

```
zoo::rollapply(a, 3, FUN=identity)
```

Of course you can specify different functions if you want to use these values to calculate something specific.

```
zoo::rollapply(a, 3, FUN=paste0, collapse='.')
zoo::rollapply(a, 3, FUN=function(x) x[3] - x[2] - x[1])
```

Comment: Yes, I can do this with apply, but any trick no to make a functions

Comment: I will try to use a replacement function "[<" but it does work also.